# Type contract is not implicitly convertible to expected type tuple in my foundry setup

Tags: solidity, foundry

I am trying to test my project, but keeps throwing an error in the test setup.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {FoodOrder} from "../src/FoodOrder.sol";
import {DeployFoodOrder} from "../script/DeployFoodOrder.s.sol";
import {HelperConfig} from "../script/HelperConfig.s.sol";

contract FoodOrderTest is Test {
    FoodOrder foodOrder;
    HelperConfig helperConfig;

    uint256 public constant SEND_VALUE = 0.1 ether;
    address USER = makeAddr("user");
    uint256 public constant STARTING_BALANCE = 10 ether;

    function setUp() external {
        DeployFoodOrder deployer = new DeployFoodOrder();
        (foodOrder, helperConfig) = deployer.run();

        vm.deal(USER, STARTING_BALANCE);
        address customer = helperConfig.activeNetworkConfig();
    }
}
```

And this is the error when Compiling

```
Error (7407): Type contract FoodOrder is not implicitly convertible to expected type tuple(contract FoodOrder,contract HelperConfig).
```

Comment: deployer variable contains the deployed contract insatance. Not a tuple. Where did you find this code snippet?